# grpc.credentials.createSsl(root_cert) is resulting in Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: No connection established in grpc-node.js

Tags: grpc, grpc-node

```
var root_cert = readFileSync(__dirname + 
'/credentials/localhosttest.cer'); 
var client = new PSC_PatientProto.service(target,grpc.credentials.createSsl(root_cert));
```

the above code is resulting in the below error

```
error in call

Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: No connection established at 
Object.callErrorFromStatus (C:\acp-electron-shell\electron- 
app\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call.js:31:26) at 
Object.onReceiveStatus (C:\acp-electron-shell\electron- 
app\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client.js:180:52)
```

Comment: Please run your code with the environment variables `GRPC_TRACE=all` and `GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG` and include the output in the question.